# Can SQL Server EKM be used with MS Certificate Service?

Tags: sql-server, certificate, pki

I am trying to implement EKM and feel current 3rd party products are a bit pricy. Can i simply use MS Certificate Service for EKM?

Thanks,
Ebe.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is no EKM provider for the Certificates Service. And that is totaly understandable, given that EKM targets hardware certificate stores and MS Certificate Service is a certificate provisioning service, not a certificate store.